# No logra registrar a traves de AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Comencemos con mi archivo llamado "registrarse_test.php"

```js
<?php 

include_once 'header.php'
?>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#enviar-btn', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var obj = {
       'first': $('#first').val().trim(),  
       'nick': $('#nick').val().trim(),
       'pwd': $('#pwd').val().trim(),
      };


      $.ajax({
       url: 'back_registrarse.php',
       method: 'POST',
       data: obj,
       success: function ( respuesta ){
          alert( respuesta.mensaje );
       },
       error: function( e, err, error ){
           //Añadimos un nodo de error, por si pasa algo en el servidor, esto lo vamos a ver en la consola de depuración
         console.log(e, err, error);
       }
      })
     });
   })
</script>

<div class="main-wrapper">

<div id="register_form"> 
<?php //<form class="signup-form" action="back_registrarse.php" method="POST"> ?>
<form id="registro-form" class="signup-form"  method="POST">  

  <h2>Registrarse</h2>

  <input id="first" type="text" name="first" placeholder="Nombre" required> 

  <input id="nick" type="text" name="nick" placeholder="nick" required> 

  <input id="pwd" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" required>

  <button id="enviar-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="registrar"> 
    Registrarme
  </button>

</form>
</div> 

<?php 

include_once'footer.php';
?>
```

luego tenemos aquí el "back_registrarse.php" que invoque arriba

```js
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'conexion.php';
//Declaramos un arreglo que será nuestro retorno
$respuesta = array();

//Primero hay que validar que las variables existan
//La superglobal $_REQUEST responde a los verbos GET y POST
if( empty( $_REQUEST['first'] ) || empty( $_REQUEST['pwd'] ) || empty( $_REQUEST['nick'] )     ){
  $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Usuario y/o password vacío';
}


else{
  //Guardamos y limpiamos las variables
$first= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST ['first']);
$pwd= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST ['pwd']);
$nick= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST ['nick']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");
  //Creamos el SQL, no siempre funciona agregando así las variables, yo recomiendo concatenar


$sql = "INSERT INTO Usuario (nombre, fecha_creacion, password, nick) VALUES ('$first','$date', '$pwd', '$nick')";

  //Validamos que la consulta esté bien hecha
  if( !$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql) ){
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Tronó la consulta';
  }

  else{
      //Aquí asignamos nuestro arreglo, assoc o array te sirven
      $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'funko el registro';

      mysqli_free_result($result);
      mysqli_close( $conn );
  }

}

//Ahora si, retornamos nuestra respuesta con formato y encabezado JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

**EDIT**

Siempre me topo con el mensaje de 'Tronó la consulta', es lo que me dice en network->preview, pero no encuentro ningún error que haya podido cometer para poder trabajar en base a ello, alguna idea de que pudo ser en este registro? De esta otra manera, mas directa, tampoco me deja insertarlos, en su lugar me dice lo que se ve en la imagen de mas abajo

```js
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'conexion.php';
//Declaramos un arreglo que será nuestro retorno
$respuesta = array();

//Primero hay que validar que las variables existan
//La superglobal $_REQUEST responde a los verbos GET y POST
if( empty( $_REQUEST['first'] ) || empty( $_REQUEST['pwd'] ) || empty( $_REQUEST['nick'] )     ){
  $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Usuario y/o password vacío';
}


else{
  //Guardamos y limpiamos las variables
$first= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST ['first']);
$pwd= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST ['pwd']);
$nick= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST ['nick']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");
  //Creamos el SQL, no siempre funciona agregando así las variables, yo recomiendo concatenar


$sql = "INSERT INTO Usuario (nombre, fecha_creacion, password, nick) VALUES ('$first','$date', '$pwd', '$nick')";

}

//Ahora si, retornamos nuestra respuesta con formato y encabezado JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ANEXO: Estructura de tabla usuario**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que estas tratando de hacer con esto? "!$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql)" el registro no se inserta en la db?

Comment: De que en caso de que no se inserte, mande el mensaje de que "tronó"

Comment: ¿Pero se registra en la base de datos?

Comment: a lo que me refiero, es que esperas que haga esa linea.. o sea.. estas tratando de negar el resultado de esa igualdad?

Comment: @Oswuell No se registra en la base de datos

Comment: ¿Has verificado si llegan las variables que envías al PHP?

Comment: @gbianchi  espero insertar con esa linea a la base de datos, adicionalmente de lanzar el mensaje si no funciona. Edite el post principal añadiendo un un codigo mas directo, y sigue sin insertar.

Comment: El codigo mas directo nunca ejecuta la consulta. Mi pregunta va basada en que mysqli_query  ya devuelve directamente true o false en ese tipo de consulta.. y puede ser que la igualdad te este dando el problema. y si no, chequea que realmente la consutla este correcta, que tengas permisos a la db, que te puedas conectar y que lleguen los parametros.. has un echo de $sql y decinos como se ve. Tambien, proba esa consulta directamente en la db.

Comment: @Oswull No, no se, como se verifica eso?

Comment: Comenta todo el código e imprime print_r($_POST);

Comment: @Oswuell me dice... Array ( [first] => Jenny [nick] => root [pwd] => 123456 ) por lo que puedo asumir que efectivamente envía los datos, pero algo pasa en back_registrarse.php que no esta permitiendo el registro entonces.

Comment: Perfecto. Verifica ahora que te estas conectando a la base de datos correctamente.

Comment: puedes poner la estrucuta de la tabla Usuario ?

Comment: @srJJ Ya agregue la imagen de la estructura de la tabla Usuario

Comment: @Oswuell efectivamente conecta a la base de dato correctamente

Comment: @Hoozuki Y el campo "id" te recomiendo que lo crees como una llave primaria. Una pregunta:  ¿El campo nick es una llave foránea?

Comment: @Oswuell cambie  el mensaje que me daba de "tronó" por esto ->$respuesta['mensaje'] = $result;<- para que me mostrara el resultado, y me dijo que me daba false

Comment: @Oswuell listo, ya lo volvi primario, el nick lo coloque como "unique" para que no se registraran personas con el mismo nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'conexion.php';

$respuesta = array();

if( empty( $_REQUEST['first'] ) || empty( $_REQUEST['pwd'] ) || empty( $_REQUEST['nick'] ))
{
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Usuario y/o password vacío';

}else{

    $first= $_REQUEST ['first'];
    $pwd= $_REQUEST ['pwd'];
    $nick= $_REQUEST ['nick'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Usuario (nombre, fecha_creacion, password, nick)
        VALUES ('".$first."', '".$date."', ".$pwd.", '".$nick."')");

    if($sql == TRUE)
    {
        $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Registrado con exito';

    }else{

        $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Error';
    }
}

//Ahora si, retornamos nuestra respuesta con formato y encabezado JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

?>

Comment: Consigo el siguiente error: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in <b>/var/www/html/crud_agenda/back_registrarse.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br /> {"mensaje":"Error"}

Trate colocando la conexión otra vez en antes del request, me deja de dar eso pero me lanza el mensaje de  "error" (pero esta vez el programado por el codigo a mostrar, el else).

Comment: @Hoozuki Prueba nuevamente.

Comment: efectivamente funcionó, Registrado con éxito, muchas gracias por la ayuda Oswuell y a los demas que me respondieron.

Comment: @Hoozuki Perfecto! Suerte!

Comment: si quieres hacer suso de `mysqli_real_escape_string()` debes pasar esas variable